# Cannot get / Node js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to start serving some static web pages using connect like this:

```
const express = require ('express');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const cors = require ('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/api/pesan', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).send();
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Aplikasi berjalan di port', port));
```

and this is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  pesan = '';

  constructor (private http: HttpClient){}

  kirim(){
    console.log(this.pesan);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/pesan', this.pesan).toPromise();
    }

 )
```

i make newfolder /backend and put server.js there. i want to connect the node with app.component.html but i get this ERROR

Comment: Please make sure to add the error message and possibly the frameworks and versions you're using.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, there are two things you want to do:

1. Create an API and return the data you have posted.
2. Call that API endpoint from your frontend and `console.log(...)` the data

Here's an updated code that should work and why it didn't work before:

#### Node Server

I simply returned the data

```
const express = require ('express');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const cors = require ('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/api/pesan', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    // UPDATED: This time, we return the data you passed
    res.status(200).send(req.body);
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Aplikasi berjalan di port', port));
```

#### Angular App

You were actually able to properly call your endpoint BUT you didn't do anything with the promise you created with `.toPromise()`. I updated the code to handle that.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  pesan = { foo: 'some awesome data' };

  constructor (private http: HttpClient){}

  kirim(){
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/pesan', this.pesan)
       .toPromise()
       .then(response => { 
          const data = response.json();
          console.log(data); 
       });
  }

}
```